# FFMPEG thumbnail in php application's is not rotated properly

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg, rotation

I have created a FFMPEG thumbnail in a php application and tried to rotate the thumbnail image if the video is bottom up(reversed).But the image rotate is not working properly.
The below is the code for image rotation

```
$video = $storeHere.$mediaFile;
                                $tImage = $upload_output['uploaded_file'].'.jpg';
                                $thumbnail = $storeHere.$tImage;
                                // shell command [highly simplified, please don't run it plain on your script!]
                                 shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg -s 250x250  $thumbnail 2>&1");
                                 /* image rotate fix */
                                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($thumbnail);
                                    $degrees = 270;
                                    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
                                    imagejpeg($rotate,$thumbnail);
                                 /* rotate fix ends */
```

Comment: php image functions suck just use image magick

Comment: Thanks mate I ll try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI I have found the solution for this one,

```
 shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg -s 250x250  $thumbnail 2>&1");
                                 /* image rotate fix *///vignesh
                                  $exif = exif_read_data($thumbnail);
                                   if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
                                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($thumbnail);
                                    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                                        case 3:
                                            $degrees = 180;
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            $degrees = -90;
                                            break;
                                        case 8:
                                            $degrees = 90;
                                            break;

                                    }
                                    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
                                    imagejpeg($rotate,$thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution still may have an issue of the video to be played every time to generate the thumbnail.
the simplest way i guess is to use the native player in your mobile to play the video
What you could do is try to use Native player API to load() content, then play() it - [longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31800/loading-new-playlists](http://longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31800/loading-new-playlists), however, there needs to be a player instance already present on the page first for this to work.