# ffmpeg: Generate video's thumbnail in original orientation in php

Tags: php, shell, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to generate thumbnail from a video. My command is working fine but it is generating thumbnail in wrong orientation.

I want to keep same orientation of the video I am using.

Here is my command:

```
exec("ffmpeg  -i  567293a3a6b48.mp4 -ss   01:00  -vframes 1  thumbnail.jpg");
```

Also thumbnail does not contain any orientation info in exif data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFMPEG thumbnail in php application's is not rotated properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759302/ffmpeg-thumbnail-in-php-applications-is-not-rotated-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue and I found these commands:

```
ffmpeg -i input -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -c copy output
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input -metadata rotate=0 -c copy output
```

Found here: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1293#p3523

This wasn't a fix for my project, maybe it will help you?  Additionally, I don't think this includes logic to determine if you need to rotate the image in the first place.